# paste code greek letters

Tags: support

When I post code here that contains greek letters, they are displayed as `\[Beta]`, then some good people modify my post to change to proper display. But how do I do this myself (and without having to write a function in mathematica that converts the something to unicode which someone suggested, I want ideally ctrl+c, ctrl+v solution).

Comment: Good question but already answered.  Please see the link inserted at the top of your post.  If for some reason that solution is not applicable for you let me know and I can reopen this.